# org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runLeaf()

Tags: java, spring-test

Pom FILE

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.learn</groupId>
<artifactId>BasicWebApp</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>BasicWebApp Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>BasicWebApp</finalName>
</build>
```

This is my business-config.xml file

> src/main/resources/business-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

</beans>
```

This is my AccountRepoTest file This is the test file.

> src/test/java/AccountRepoTest.java

```
package com.core.repositories;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:business-config.xml")
public class AccountRepoTest {

      @Test
      public void test()
      {

      }//end of test

}//end of Class
```

This is my error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runLeaf(Lorg/junit/runners/model/Statement;Lorg/junit/runner/Description;Lorg/junit/runner/notification/RunNotifier;)V
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

I don't know what's happening for this project. I tried it in a different project and its working. But I am not being able to find the error for this one.

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace here not as a link to an Image.

Comment: Mostly the reason for a `NoSuchMethodError` is an incompatible jar

Comment: @Jens I have edited the error. You can check the complete stacktrace. I guess all the jars are working fine because I tried this in a different project where it was working. I don't know whats going wrong in this part. Any other suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you switch the version of JUnit to `4.9`?

Answer (score 2):

The `runLeaf()` method mentioned in your stack trace was introduced in JUnit 4.9.

Thus you apparently are executing against JUnit version 4.8 or earlier within Eclipse.

Make sure that you have your classpath in Eclipse configured to use JUnit 4.9 or later with `spring-test` 3.1.x. Perhaps refreshing your Maven configuration will help (assuming you imported the project as a Maven project in Eclipse).